# Colour and greyscale images

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, grayscale

I am trying to construct a model which converts greyscale images to colour images. So I used combination of colour images and greyscale images for training the cnn model. Though accuracy of training and loss is good but the val loss is high and Val accuracy is low compared to the actual one, thus I concluded that it is overfitting, although I applied dropouts, batch normalisation, image augmentation. The result is same. So, I think that due to sending half images as colour and other half has greyscale images the model is getting overfitted. How do I overcome it?

Comment: Do you really believe that one can retrieve a color from a gray ?

Comment: No, but I had seen ieee paper which they trained on greyscale and colour images to colour images but not in total maybe like 70-80% they were able to colour the images. So just wanted to give a try how it works

Comment: @YvesDaoust "retrieve" is a big word. The OP is asking for "convert", but I guess "plausibly hallucinate" would be more appropriate. It is an active area of research, and recent results on natural scenes are impressive.

Comment: @FrancescoCallari: to convert gray to RGB, triplicate all components. If by convert you mean "assign random colors", well, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the work done by jantic at the deOldify project: https://github.com/jantic/DeOldify . When it works the results are impressive.